# Consume SOAP WS in Clojure

Tags: clojure, soap-client

Currently in our project, we're using *io.xapix/paos* clojure library to communicate with a SOAP WS. The library brings in few unlicensed transitive dependencies with it. So, we want an alternative to the paos library.

> List of actions performed till now:
>
> 1. Tried to exclude the transitive dependency, but it didn't go well, met ClassNotFoundException :(
> 2. Tried to check clj-soap, but that seems to me not maintained anymore

Can anyone from the community can help us finding an alternative to paos.

Comment: You cannot just exclude a dependency, you have to replace it with a functionally equivalent one.  Even if `Zeto-Ltd/clj-soap` has not been updated in a few years, perhaps it works well enough for your needs?  Can you share the name of the dependency and what you don't like about the license?

Comment: It's  wsrf/wsrf-xbeans "1.0" , and it doesn't have any license. Maven central link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/wsrf/wsrf-xbeans/1.0

Comment: From what I could tell, the lib contains code that is generated by a program from a spec.  And therefore does not have an explicit license.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve deps only with the locally downloaded jar + extra wsdl4j-fixed. It works but it is a workaround, not an elegant solution.

```clj
{:mvn/repos 
 {"enonic"   {:url "https://repo.enonic.com/public/"}}
 :deps
 {io.xapix/paos {:mvn/version "0.2.5"}
  wsrf/wsrf-xbeans {:local/root "wsrf-xbeans-1.0.jar"}
  wsdl4j/wsdl4j {:mvn/version "1.6.2-fixed"}}}
```